# No module named 'x'; 'x' is not a package

Tags: python, tkinter, import, module

This is the error that appears when I try to import other [tkinter](/questions/tagged/tkinter) files with the use of a button:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Feargus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Feargus\Documents\COMPUTING\games\BIG_MAIN_MENU.py", line 13, in settingsButton
    import SETTINGS.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SETTINGS.py'; 'SETTINGS' is not a package
```

Here is the code which imports the files:

```
def startGame():
     import GAME.py



def settingsButton():
    import SETTINGS.py
    quit()



def leaderBoard():
    import Leaderboard.py
    quit()



def endGame():
    quit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding the .py extensions for all your import statements. You just need the file names when importing Python modules so

`import SETTINGS` instead of `import SETTINGS.py`

would be the correct way to format it.

The same goes to the other imports as well.

Comment: Ah thank you so much!! I thought it was way more complicated to solve than this but its so simple. Thank you its very appreciated!